# SmsManager in android not working

Tags: android, smsmanager

I'm developing an android application that gets the latitude and the longitude and sends it to a person with sms. The problem that I have is that the other person is not receiving my sms. Can you please see what's going on?? I'm working with it since this morning and it drives me bananas.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

        Button sendSMS;
        TextView txtLocation;

        Context context;

        double lat, lng;
        LocationManager locationManager;
        Location location;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            sendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send_sms);
            txtLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_location);
            sendSMS.setOnClickListener(this);

            context = getApplicationContext();

            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
            criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
            criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
            criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
            criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            if (packageManager.checkPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, getPackageName()) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10000, 100, locationListener);
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                getCoordinates(location);
            }
        }

        private void getCoordinates(Location l){
            if (l != null) {
                lat = l.getLatitude();
                lng = l.getLongitude();
                txtLocation.setText(Latitude: + " " + lat + "\n" + Longitude + " " + lng);
            }
            else{
                txtLocation.setText("No location found yet");
            }
        }

@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent;
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.button_send_sms:
                    String number;
                    String msgbody;
                    number = "0123456789";
                    if(lat!=0 && lng!=0) {
                        msgbody = "My location is: http://google.com/maps/place/" + lat + "," + lng;
                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, msgbody, null, null);
                        Toast.makeText("Message sent"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText("Message didn't send"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                getCoordinates(location);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }
        };
    }
```

The result that I get in my phone screen is the Toast "Message sent" but I can't see any sms received in the other phone and there is no error in my logcat. When I press the button, the logcat writes:

```
12-07 00:15:54.494 28690-28690/emmanouilvaresis.findtheold D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
```

And also the AndroidManifest has all the permissions for the sms.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Can you please tell me why the sms is not sent? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found a solution. The message was above 70 characters.